# reading the first value using simplexml

Tags: php, simplexml, simplexmlrpcserver

I am using simplexml to read all the child nodes successfully. But how do I read the "NumCrds"?

```
<ACCOUNT NumCrds="1">
<ACCNO>some Bank</ACCNO>
<CURRCODE>CAD</CURRCODE>
<ACCTYPE>00</ACCTYPE>
</ACCOUNT>
```

I have read it somewhere in the PHP manual but I am unable to find it now.

```
$my_num_cards=$sxe->ACCOUNT['NumCrds'];
```

This is printing the number 1 for all the records even if there are values like 2, 3 in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes can be accessed using array indexes:

```
$data = '<ACCOUNT NumCrds="1">
<ACCNO>some Bank</ACCNO>
<CURRCODE>CAD</CURRCODE>
<ACCTYPE>00</ACCTYPE>
</ACCOUNT>
';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

// this outputs 1
echo $xml['NumCrds'];
```

It is also possible to use the [SimpleXMLElement::attributes()](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) function to returns a list of all of the attribute key/value pairs.

```
$attributes = $xml->attributes();
echo $attributes['NumCrds'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either `$attrs = $el->attributes(); echo $attrs['NumCrds']` or just `echo $el['NumCrds']`. Attributes are reflected as array elements, while sub-tags are reflected as object properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_num_cards=$item->attributes()->NumCrds;
```

This is what I was looking for. Thanks for all your help.

http://fr.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php#94433